# side by side tables latex - without \floatrow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, r

I have the following simplified document ():

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}%

\begin{table}[ht]
\subfloat[]{\scalebox{1.5}{\input{./ta}}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\scalebox{1.5}{\input{./tb}}}
\caption{Caption about here}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It refers to two simple tables `ta.tex` and `tb.tex` they are as follows:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.5.2 by xtable 1.8-3 package
% Thu Jan 17 09:17:38 2019
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
 & Other Debriefs \\ 
  \hline
1 & nothing here \\ 
   \hline
1 & nothing here \\ 
   \hline
1 & nothing here \\ 
   \hline
1 & nothing here \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
 & Other Reviews \\ 
  \hline
1 & Every week \\ 
  2 & nada \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Because the tables contain unequal number of rows they are not top - aligned. Instead they are vertically centered side by side. Can the above code be modified so that the 2 tables are vertically top-aligned? I found a solution where `floatrow` package - but unfortunately it conflicts with `float` - which I need for the images to be placed where they should be (I am working in R markdown, I am very inexperienced with Latex). Essentially this would be a modification to Marcin Kosiński's solution [Side by side Xtables in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926671/side-by-side-xtables-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. If I ask the same question on `tex` forum - will it be against the rules?

Comment: Cross-posting is often discouraged, so be careful. Occasionally somebody will come up rather strongly in a comment on one or both, so I suggest against it. Since you accepted the answer below, if you have further related problems, I recommend you make the next question add sufficient purpose, and consider which site is best and post there. In this case, since nothing about it is in R, perhaps the other site would work well (better?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack perhaps, but it is the way I usually work. I make my layout good enough and then go back at the end and do hard tweaks like this to make it ready for publication. Essentially, you are putting your table objects in minipage containers to isolate them and then subtracting a little space before the second one to force it up:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{1.5}{\input{./ta}}}\quad
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-13mm}
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{1.5}{\input{./tb}}}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Caption about here}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, very useful, I will make note of this. I temporarily solved this by making R replace via `gsub` in sub-tables the first line from `\begin{tabular}{rl}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}` - not fully sure why it works, but it does.

Comment: Right, that is a better solution, I missed you were using `float` without specifying the alignment. [t] is top aligned: (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: How would you specify alignment at the document level then?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}%

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
  \hline
 & Other Debriefs \\
  \hline
1 & nothing here \\
1 & nothing here \\
1 & nothing here \\
1 & nothing here \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{}\label{tab:a}
\end{subtable}
\hfil
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
  \hline
 & Other Reviews    \\
  \hline
1 & Every week      \\
2 & nada            \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{}\label{tab:b}
\end{subtable}
    \caption{Caption about here}
    \label{tab:ab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate a page layout)